# Cannot load CLoader with pyyaml

Tags: python, pyyaml

I'm working on a python project using pyyaml. I need to run it in a Docker container based on bitnami/minideb:jessie. Python version is 2.7.9.
The original code is using CLoader and I cannot change it currently.
Any reason CLoader fails to load but Loader is fine ?

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.__version__
'3.12'
>>> from yaml import Loader
>>> from yaml import CLoader
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name CLoader
>>>
```

I cannot figure out what I'm missing here. Any idea ?

Running it from the Docker image python:2.7.9 does not raise any error then:

```
$ docker run -ti python:2.7.9 bash
#/ python
>>> from yaml import CLoader
>>> from yaml import Loader
>>>
```

Comment: Might be worth opening a GitHub issue: https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues

It's not just you, I was able to reproduce this.

Comment: https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/108

Answer (score 5):

By default, the setup.py script checks whether LibYAML is installed
and if so, builds and installs LibYAML bindings.

This is the minimum to get CLoader compiled and installed.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3 python3-dev python3-pip gcc libyaml-dev
RUN pip3 install pyyaml
# verify
RUN python3 -c "import yaml; yaml.CLoader"
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. You need to install the libyaml-dev package, then install libyaml and pyyaml from source. Here's the complete `Dockerfile` for `minideb:jessie`:

```
FROM bitnami/minideb:jessie

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
        automake \
        autoconf \
        build-essential \
        git-core \
        libtool \
        libyaml-dev \
        make \
        python \
        python-dev \
        python-pip

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install Cython==0.29.10

RUN mkdir /libyaml
WORKDIR /libyaml
RUN git clone https://github.com/yaml/libyaml.git . && \
    git checkout dist-0.2.2 && \
    autoreconf -f -i && \
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make install

RUN mkdir /pyyaml
WORKDIR /pyyaml
RUN git clone https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml.git . && \
    git checkout 5.1.1 && \
    python setup.py install

RUN python -c "import yaml; from yaml import CLoader; print 'Loaded CLoader!'"
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of additions to others' solutions:

If you want the install command to hard-fail if the libyaml C extension won't build (instead of silently falling back to a pure-Python only install), you can pass the `--with-libyaml` global option, eg: `python setup.py --with-libyaml install`.

If you're doing this with something that might ever need to be upgraded (eg implicitly via another package's requirement for a higher pyyaml version), it's better to use `pip` instead of directly calling `setup.py`, as that (currently) uses a pure distutils installation, which pip will fail to uninstall later. You'll see an error like "ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyYAML'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall."

Doing the required extension build with pip looks something like `pip install --global-option='--with-libyaml' pyyaml`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the step mentions, and the following steps fixed my issue.

Install

```
apt-get install -y gcc libyaml-dev
pip install --ignore-installed --global-option='--with-libyaml' pyyaml
```

Test

```
python -c "import yaml; yaml.CLoader"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just copying the developer's answer from the [issue](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/108#issuecomment-370459912) linked above, but this happens because pyyaml only installs the libyaml bindings (CLoader & co.) if it finds the libyaml-dev package (that's the debian package, anyway) at install time. If it doesn't find it, it prints a warning and skips the libyaml bindings.

So, install libyaml-dev before installing pyyaml.